# my application stops working as soon as launched

Tags: android, xml, gps, sms, program-entry-point

(ANDROID    GPS)
i made this application to send gps coordinates via sms but the app crashes(as soon as i open it) can somebody help me

logcat images
[logcal image1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iprwr7e5h1mzl37/002.jpg)

[log cat image 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/htwyh2n5ri1b8xk/003.jpg)

MainActivity.java

```
package com.adzz.gps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.location.Location; 
import android.location.LocationListener; 
import android.location.LocationManager;   
import android.content.Context; 
import android.telephony.SmsManager; 
import android.view.Gravity; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.TextView; 
import android.widget.Toast; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;     


public class MainActivity extends Activity { 
     String m; 

 @Override 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
 setContentView(R.layout.main); 
 LocationManager manager= (LocationManager) 
this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
 LocationListener listener =new LocationListener() { 
 @Override 

 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { 
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

 } 

 @Override 
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { 
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

 } 

 @Override 
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { 
 } 
 @Override 
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
 final String phoneNumber="9453603045"; 

 double lat1=location.getLatitude(); 
 Double d1= new Double(lat1); 
 double longi1=location.getLongitude(); 
 Double d2=new Double(longi1); 
 m="latitude = "+ d1.toString() + "and latitude = "+ d2.toString(); 
 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
 smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, m, null, null); 
 TextView lat= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat); 
 TextView longi=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.longi); 

 lat.setText("latitude = "+lat1); 
 longi.setText("longitude ="+longi1); 
 } 
 }; 
 manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 25, 
listener); 
 Button b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); 
 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

 @Override 
 public void onClick(View v) { 

 Toast toast=Toast.makeText(Main.this, m, 5000); 
 toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); 
 toast.show(); 
 } 
 }); 
 } 

 @Override 
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
 // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 
 return true; 
 } 

}
```

---

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.adzz.gps001"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.adzz.gps001.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file you must include

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

Read the documentation under "Requesting User Permissions" for more details. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 0):

Your app is failing because you need to add the android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to your manifest file.